# Decoding binary Android xml resources in Android

Tags: java, android, decompiling, aapt

I am trying to make an Android app that can decompile other Android apps.
I have just started, but I am stuck while trying to correctly process resources of the type xml, i.e. the ones stored under res/xml/.

The problem I am facing is that these files contain binary information(as far as I understand, aapt converts XML files into binary during the packaging process.)

**Also, I am aware of the existence of tools like apktool, or the dump command of aapt itself. However, these are PC based tools, whereas I need to decode the XML resources in an Android app.**

So, is there a way to do it in Android, or do I need to go through the aapt code and port the related code to Android?

Edit: I have also tried the [Resources Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html), using the [getXml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int)) function, which returns a [XmlResourceParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html), but could not get it to work, because of the binary nature of the xml file.

Edit(2) : Based on the solitary answer, I integrated [ApkParser](https://github.com/clearthesky/apk-parser) into my code.  It works well for most parts, except that for certain XML files, such as the XML resources found in framework-res.apk, the values for the XML attributes were decoded incorrectly. For example, all the boolean values in the XML were reported as "false", while the actual XML had some attributes with "true" values as well. So, I guess the ApkParser has some limitations.

I found the following [issue](https://github.com/clearthesky/apk-parser/issues/26) on Github for the project, which shares some aspects of the problem I am facing.

Kindly suggest other alternatives.

Comment: To whoever is downvoting, please mention the reasons for doing so

Answer (score 0):

There is a java library that does what you asked. 
You can try integrating it within your app.

Here: [apk-parser - Apk parser lib for java](https://github.com/clearthesky/apk-parser).

Or, try contacting [HootanParsa](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4070451) whose *MiXplorer* does it with ease.